# Multiple SqlCommand parameters with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, parameters

I have a query with multiple named parameters having same name for which I have to pass values. Consider following example (query in code behind not stored procedure):

```
Dim stSqlQry As String = "Select fld1, fld2, fld3 From tbl1 Where fld3=@fld3
    AND fld1 NOT IN(Select Distinct fld1 From tbl2 Where fld3=@fld3)
    AND fld2 NOT IN(Select Distinct fld2 From tbl3 Where fld3=@fld3)"
```

I pass value to fld3 using following snippet:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand(stSqlQry)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fld3", fld3_val)
```

When run it gives **Scalar Variable Error** for @fld3 (and in debug fld3_val has a value). So as a workaround I have used it as follows declaring three named parameters `fld3_1, fld3_2, fld3_3`:

```
Dim stSqlQry As String = "Select fld1, fld2, fld3 From tbl1 Where fld3=@fld3_1
    AND fld1 NOT IN(Select Distinct fld1 From tbl2 Where fld3=@fld3_2)
    AND fld2 NOT IN(Select Distinct fld2 From tbl3 Where fld3=@fld3_3)"
```

And passed same value to `fld3_1, fld3_2, fld3_3` using following snippet:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand(stSqlQry)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fld3_1", fld3_val)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fld3_2", fld3_val)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fld3_3", fld3_val)
```

Second one works perfect, was the first format incorrect in code behind? And is there any way by which we can pass value to multiple SQL parameters using single `SqlCommand Parameter`?

Comment: Not sure why the first one failed with that error message. Could you try to change the first call removing the AddWithValue and use _Add(param, type).Value = value_ syntax?

Comment: Sure, I'll try that format also and let you know the result.

Comment: I'm guessing you are working with inline sql and not stored procedures. with a stored procedure there is no problem to use the same parameter multiple times, but with inline sql every `@` sign is basically like declaring a new variable, therefor you get an error. either use the workaround you have or write a stored procedure. I'd suggest a stored procedure.

Comment: @ZoharPeled All code is in code behind, no stored procedure. I've yet to try Steve's suggestion. Updated my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @haraman well in that case I don't think Steve's suggestion will help. AddWithValud is considered bad practice since it forces ado.net to infer the parameter type from the value and that might cause some problems but this is not one of them. I do suggest changing to a stored procedure.

Comment: @Steve *Add(param, type).Value = value syntax* syntax is working. But I wonder why AddWithValue doesn't. Thinking about *type* I checked the structure of all linked tables, even the type of parameter columns is same (BigInt). Anyhow, thanks for suggestion

Comment: There are known problems with AddWithValue. [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: After your comment, I came across this link and read whole blog post, that's why I thought about confirming the column type of all those tables. So I'll consider *stop using and replacing all AddWithValue* in all my apps

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me and might work for you is to single out the field names.

```
Dim stSqlQry As String = "Select [fld1], [fld2], [fld3] From [tbl1] Where [fld3] = @fld3 AND [fld1] NOT IN(Select Distinct [fld1] From [tbl2] Where [fld3] = @fld3) AND [fld2] NOT IN(Select Distinct [fld2] From [tbl3] Where [fld3] = @fld3)"
```